# how can I print dynamic array in c++ I need explanation to this question

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

**This is the question my teacher gave me**:

- Construct a structure `Employee` that consists of the following fields:
  `ID`, `name`, `degree`, `age`
- A function that creates an object (a variable of `Employee` type), fills it from the user the, then returns it.
- A function that receives an object (a variable of `Employee` type) and prints its fields.
- Inside the main function:

  - Ask the user to specify the number of employees.
  - Create a dynamic array of the size specified by the user for the employees.
  - Inside a loop, fill the array elements one at a time by calling the first function.
  - Inside another loop, print the array elements one at a time by calling the second function.

I tried to solve it although I didn't understand it and this is what I have, Pleas help:

```cpp
struct Employee
{
    int ID;
    char name[10];
    char degree;
    int age;

};

int fillin()
{   Employee employee;
    cout<<"Enter employee ID, NAME, DEGREE and AGE:\n";
    cin>>employee.ID;
    cin>>employee.name;
    cin>>employee.degree;
    cin>>employee.age;

}

int print()
{
    Employee employee;
    cout<<"ID: "<< employee.ID<<" , ";
    cout<<"NAME: "<< employee.name<<" , ";
    cout<<"Degree: "<< employee.degree<<" , ";
    cout<<"AGE: "<< employee.age<<".\n ";
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    cout<<"Enter number of employees: ";
    cin>> num;

   string *name= new string[num];

    for(int i = 0; i < num;i++)
    {
      name[i]=fillin();
    }


    for(int j : name){
        print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The same as you would a regular array.

Comment: 10 seems short for a name field, and 1 character seems odd for a degree.

Comment: you need to provide an arguement for `print` and correct return type for `fillin`

Comment: For starters, you need to create an array of  `Employee` not `string`: `Employee * employees = new Employee[num];`

Comment: Also use `std::vector`

Comment: `employee` should be passed as an argument to `print`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function can have *parameters* and return a value. So here, `fillin` should return an `Employee` object, and `print` should take an `Employee` (or better a const reference) parameter:

```
Employee fillin()
{   Employee employee;
    cout<<"Enter employee ID, NAME, DEGREE and AGE:\n";
    cin>>employee.ID;
    cin>>employee.name;
    cin>>employee.degree;
    cin>>employee.age;
    return employee;      // return the local object
}

void print(const Employee& employee)
{
    cout<<"ID: "<< employee.ID<<" , ";
    cout<<"NAME: "<< employee.name<<" , ";
    cout<<"Degree: "<< employee.degree<<" , ";
    cout<<"AGE: "<< employee.age<<".\n ";
}
```

Your main function could become:

```
int main()
{
    int num;
    cout<<"Enter number of employees: ";
    cin>> num;

   Employee *name= new Employee[num];

    for(int i = 0; i < num;i++)
    {
      name[i]=fillin();
    }


    for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
        print(name[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, you should check that the input methods return valid values (check `cin` after each read)

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the code, below is the working example.

- the functions should receive and return parameters somehow, references are used in the code
- array should be of appropriate type
- wrong iterator used

However, keep in mind that there are more issues with the code, like no boundary checking, it is better to use STL library... consider this just as a starting point.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Employee
{
    int ID;
    char name[10];
    char degree;
    int age;

};

int fillin(Employee& employee)
{   
    cout<<"Enter employee ID, NAME, DEGREE and AGE:\n";
    cin>>employee.ID;
    cin>>employee.name;
    cin>>employee.degree;
    cin>>employee.age;
}

int print(const Employee& employee)
{
    cout<<"ID: "<< employee.ID<<" , ";
    cout<<"NAME: "<< employee.name<<" , ";
    cout<<"Degree: "<< employee.degree<<" , ";
    cout<<"AGE: "<< employee.age<<".\n ";
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    cout<<"Enter number of employees: ";
    cin>> num;

    Employee *emp= new Employee[num];

    for(int i = 0; i < num;i++)
    {
      fillin(emp[i]);
    }


    for(int j = 0; j< num; j++){
        print(emp[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Employee fillin()
    {
        Employee employee;
        cout << "Enter employee ID, NAME, DEGREE and AGE:\n";
        cin >> employee.ID;
        cin >> employee.name;
        cin >> employee.degree;
        cin >> employee.age;

        return employee;
    }

void print(Employee emp)
    {
        cout << "ID: " << emp.ID << " , ";
        cout << "NAME: " << emp.name << " , ";
        cout << "Degree: " << emp.degree << " , ";
        cout << "AGE: " << emp.age << ".\n ";
    }
```

This should help put you on the right track. You just need the dynamic array to accept Employee objects and then you need to supply the objects to print when you call print(someEmployeeObject) in main.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have a variety of comments on your code. First, do not use character arrays. Use string instead:

```
#include <string>

struct Employee
{
    int ID;
    std::string name;
    char degree;
    int age;
};
```

String allows for dynamic-length strings, so if someone enters a really, really long name, you won't overrun the space. It will just handle it. Plus there are a bunch of other advantages.

Next, let's change this method just slightly:

```
Employee fillin() {
    Employee employee;
    cout<<"Enter employee ID, NAME, DEGREE and AGE:\n";
    cin>>employee.ID;
    cin>>employee.name;
    cin>>employee.degree;
    cin>>employee.age;
    return employee;
}
```

You weren't returning anything at all, but you need to return the employee you're creating. So this is a small change.

And now a small change to the print method:

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &ostr, const Employee &employee) {
{
    ostr <<"ID: "<< employee.ID<<" , ";
    ostr <<"NAME: "<< employee.name<<" , ";
    ostr <<"Degree: "<< employee.degree<<" , ";
    ostr <<"AGE: "<< employee.age<<".\n ";
    return ostr;
}
```

Then to use it:

```
std::cout << employee;
```

This is the C++ way to do it and lets you use the exact same method if you want to dump the employee somewhere else (like a file).

And finally, small changes to your main:

#include 
int main()
{
std::vector employees;
int num;
cout<<"Enter number of employees: ";
cin>> num;

```
for(int i = 0; i < num;i++)
{
    employees.push_back(fillin());
}

for (const Employee &employee: employees) {
    std::cout << employee;
}

return 0;
```

}

Let's talk about this. First, rather than using a fixed-length array, we're using a vector. This is a dynamic-length array similar to how string is a dynamic length string. You can push_back() to append items to the array. When defining it, you specify what it holds. So in this case, I have a vector of Employee objects.

I started with your for-loop, but I call the new version of fillin to actually get an employee record, and then I push them into the vector.

Then there's a second for-loop. You may not be familiar with this style. Basically that's a for-loop that iterates over every element of employees -- the ones we just did push_back() on. And then I use the output method I wrote earlier.

You were close. You were just missing a few key things -- basically passing elements into your methods and returning elements.